# C# dynamically group based on a condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I am trying to dynamically group a list based on a certain condition like this:

```cs
var groupedList = applyChargeActive
    ? dataList.GroupBy(s => new
    {
        s.Id,
        s.ValidFrom,
        s.ValidTo,
        s.IsActive,
        s.ApplyCharges
    })
    : dataList.GroupBy(s => new
    {
        s.Id,
        s.ValidFrom,
        s.ValidTo,
        s.IsActive
    });
```

But I am getting this error

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
> no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<<anonymous
> type: string Id,  System.DateTime? ValidFrom, System.DateTime?
> ValidTo, bool? IsActive, bool? ApplyCharges>,
> WebApi.ViewModels.CMS.BulkUpdateViewModel>>' and
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<<anonymous
> type: string Id,  System.DateTime? ValidFrom, System.DateTime?
> ValidTo, bool? IsActive>, WebApi.ViewModels.CMS.BulkUpdateViewModel>>'

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The result is not the same as the keys are different, so they cant be assigned to the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use "dummy" column in the group by:

```cs
var groupedList = applyChargeActive
    ? dataList
        .GroupBy(s => new
        {
            s.Id,
            s.ValidFrom,
            s.ValidTo,
            s.IsActive,
            s.ApplyCharges
        })
    : dataList
        .GroupBy(s => new
        {
            s.Id,
            s.ValidFrom,
            s.ValidTo,
            s.IsActive,
            ApplyCharges = false // assuming s.ApplyCharges is bool
        });
```

So the types matches.

Other than that - you might need to write different queries from this point or extract some helper method.